# Have NSWindow participate in application switcher for LSUIElement=1 app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I have an "agent" Cocoa app (`LSUIElement=1`) that shows a normal window when the user clicks on the menu bar icon.

Is it possible to have the window participate in the application switcher (i.e. the app icon show up in the list of icons when the user presses `Command+Tab`)?

Just to be clear: I do not want a dock icon or a menu. Just the application switcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application switcher does not list windows, only applications, and it does not list any application that doesn't have a Dock tile. (Indeed, last I checked, it's provided by the Dock.) So no, this isn't possible.

It might be worth a bug report: Arguably, any application that has a window up, the user should be able to ⌘⇥ back to (especially if they used ⌘⇥ to switch away from it). The current implementation does not make getting back to such a window easy.

Comment: That makes sense. Too bad there's no way to disable the dock icon after it has been enabled (without relaunching the app)...

Comment: Actually, you can [enable and disable the dock icon](https://gist.github.com/2044955) without relaunching the app. Beware, this code uses undocumented APIs.